# How to Pass selected values of multiple select component into my API?

Tags: vue.js, multiple-select

I am using vuesax multiple select component to select multiple options from the available options. But when I try to submit/Insert the selected value to my API, the values from the component are being passed as arrays. But my API accepts only string values. Can anyone help me with code to this problem?

Vuesax component code

```
    <vs-select multiple autocomplete v-model="newRecord.required_sub" label="Subject" class="selectExample mt-5 w-full" name="item-category" v-validate="'required'">
      <vs-select-item :key="item.value" :value="item.value" :text="item.text" v-for="item in teach_mode_drop" />
      </vs-select>
```

my script for options

```
teach_mode_drop: [
    {text:'Option1', value:'Option1'},
    {text:'Option2', value:'Option2'},
    {text:'Option3', value:'Option3'},
    {text:'Option4', value:'Option4'},

  ],
```

main method

```
    createRecord() {

        this.$vs.loading();

           jwt.createLeads(this.newRecord).then((response) => {

            this.$vs.loading.close();

               this.$vs.notify({
                  title: 'Success',
                  text: response.data.message,
                  iconPack: 'feather',
                  icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                  color: 'success'
              }); 


            this.$store.dispatch("userManagement/upsertToState", { type: "Leads", data: response.data.leads });

           this.newRecord.first_name  = this.newRecord.last_name = this.newRecord.email_id = this.newRecord.phone_number = this.newRecord.location = this.newRecord.required_sub =''


        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)

            this.$vs.loading.close();


            this.$vs.notify({
                title: 'Error',
                text: 'There was an error creating the Lead',
                iconPack: 'feather',
                icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                color: 'danger'
            });
        });

    },
```

Comment: You can use `.toString()` method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp

Comment: can you please help with vue.Js, if possible with code ?

Comment: can u add sample input and output what you want ? @surhyanarayan

Comment: My question has been improvised, can u please check now? @Dcoder